# Radio Button is not selected with GET Request Django FormModel

Tags: django, django-forms, radio-button

Radio button Django is getting rendered in the form but the problem is when I try to get the selected Radio Button. It isn't selecting as per the value in the database. It just shows to select from the Radio Button
I am able to POST but not GET.

Model.py

```
class myModel(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICES = [(1, 'Ok'), (2, 'Not Ok')]
   left_leg = models.BooleanField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                     default=1,
                                     null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class myModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
   model = myModel
   fields = ('left_leg')
   widgets = {'left_leg': forms.RadioSelect}
```

views.py

```
  def myview(request, pk):
      aa =  myModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
      if request.method == 'POST':
         form = myModelForm(request.POST, instance=aa)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/")
else:
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "aa.html", context)
```

aa.html

```
  <div class="col-lg-2">
     <div class="form-group">
                                  
         {{ form.left_leg.errors }}
               {% for choice in form.left_leg%}                                                
                   {{ choice }}
               {% endfor %}
                                                    
      </div>
  </div>
```

url.py

```
path('path/update/<int:pk>/',
     myView,
     name='xx'),
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Choice must be True and False instead of 1 and 0